# How to carry two check-in luggage in United in March 2021?

Tags: luggage, check-in, united-airlines

As of March 2021, we can carry only one check in luggage (per person) in New Delhi - New York United flight. We can pay $100 for an extra check-in luggage. I was wondering if there is any cheaper way to carry total two check-in luggage per person in United international flights. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Clarified that one check in bag per person.

Comment: Luggage limits are almost always per-person, not per whole-traveling-group. What is the _actual wording about luggage_ on your reservation or ticket?

Comment: The ticket says that one check in luggage per person is allowed.

Comment: With that wording, you're limited (as you say) to one check-in luggage per person. If you wish to carry two per person, you'll have to pay extra.

Comment: I know you have to pay $100 to carry an extra check in luggage. I was wondering if there is any other way to avoid this extra fee such as some subscribing to some service, etc.

Comment: I've heard of nothing other than the perks that may come with an airline frequent flyer or elite status.

Comment: @soham It’s a long shot but have you checked out the cost of upgrading your ticket? In the past I’ve booked premium class with other airlines because the extras included meant that it was not much more expensive than economy class + cost of extra hold luggage

Comment: @Traveller I checked the cost of upgrading to United Premium Plus and it's huge.